# Calculating date field based on another date field

Tags: javascript, date

I need to create a form with 2 date fields.
User will enter first date field (start-date) and I need to calculate 4 weeks from start date in the second date field (one-month-expiry). Better still: is there a way to calculate 1 calendar month instead of weeks?

I've managed to get the second field to populate a date - but it's not correct.

This is JavaScript, which I don't really understand. I've managed to get this far just by googling.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('one-month-expiry').value
            = (new Date(document.getElementById('start-date').valueAsDate
                            + (6.04e+8 * 4)))
                    .format("dd/MM/yyyy");
</script>
```

It keeps returning the same date (29/01/1970). So I've obviously managed to stuff something up.

Any ideas how to include the first date field as part of my calculation?

Comment: Oh sorry. This is javascript, which I don't really understand. I've managed to get this far just by googling.

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById('one-month-expiry').value = (new Date( document.getElementById('start-date').valueAsDate+(6.04e+8 * 4))).format("dd/MM/yyyy");


</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let date = new Date(document.getElementById('start-date').valueAsDate);
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
    document.getElementById('one-month-expiry').value = date.format("dd/MM/yyyy");
</script>
```

Beware that this might have some issues with edge cases. For example, adding one month to 31st January will give you 31st February, which does not exist, causing the date to roll over to 2nd March instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date